# UniSharp/Laravel Filemanager and TinyMCE integration

Tags: javascript, laravel, wysiwyg, tinymce-4, file-manager

I have done a fresh installation of laravel project just to try out tinyMCE with UniSharp filemanager. I have done the UniSharp + tinyMCE instalation following the guide on the github https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager.

The WYSIWYG editor is showing up correctly in the browser and I am also able to click the image upload button. However, I get the screen showing Objec not found error.

[Object Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CV5C.png)

My code for the set up looks like this. Original!

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
          <textarea name="content" class="form-control my-editor"></textarea>
          <script>
            var editor_config = {
              path_absolute : "/",
              selector: "textarea.my-editor",
              plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
              ],
              toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media",
              relative_urls: false,
              file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
                var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
                var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

                var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
                if (type == 'image') {
                  cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
                } else {
                  cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
                }

                tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
                  file : cmsURL,
                  title : 'Filemanager',
                  width : x * 0.8,
                  height : y * 0.8,
                  resizable : "yes",
                  close_previous : "no"
                });
              }
            };

            tinymce.init(editor_config);
          </script>
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

As I said - it is fresh Laravel Project with the tinyMCE and UniSharp guided setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try and change absolute_path to as path_absolute : "http://localhost/project-name/public/"

the whole script would look like this

```
<script>
    var editor_config = {
        path_absolute : "http://localhost/project-name/public/",
        selector: "textarea.my-editor",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media",
        relative_urls: false,
        file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
            var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
            var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

            var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
            if (type == 'image') {
                cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
            } else {
                cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
            }

            tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
                file : cmsURL,
                title : 'Filemanager',
                width : x * 0.8,
                height : y * 0.8,
                resizable : "yes",
                close_previous : "no"
            });
        }
    };

    tinymce.init(editor_config);
</script>
```

Comment: path_absolute : "http://localhost/project-name/public/" .. this would be even more clear

Answer (score -1):

You can try Laravel Simple File Manager. 3 simple steps for installation and very easy to integrate with TinyMCE, CKEditor or summernote.

**GitHub:** https://github.com/haruncpi/laravel-simple-filemanager

TinyMce Integration

```
<textarea id="tinymce">

<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#tinymce',
            plugins:'image',
            file_browser_callback: filemanager.tinyMceCallback
        });
    }
</script>
```

Details documentation of [Laravel Simple File Manager](https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-simple-filemanager)